# Overwrite WordPress Plugin Filter

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter

I'm trying to change some basic text that is generated by a wordpress plugin. I noticed it's using an "apply_filters" to echo the text. The text I'm trying to change is "My Job Packages" inside the first statement.

```
if ( 'job_listing' === $type ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_wc_paid_listings_packages_title', __( 'My Job Packages', 'wp-job-manager-wc-paid-listings' ), $type );
} else {
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_wc_paid_listings_packages_title', __( 'My Resume Packages', 'wp-job-manager-wc-paid-listings' ), $type );
}
```

I've tried copying the file into my child-theme folder and changing it manually, but I haven't gotten success with that. My google searches have lead me to believe I might be able to override this within my functions.php file, but I'm new to filters and could use some help.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to give me a hand :)